# Is the solution to this 1st order matrix ODE uniquely determined?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I have a matrix function $e(t)$ (i.e. for each $t$, $e(t)$ is a matrix) and the ODE
$$
e'(t)=e(t)^{-T}g(t)
$$
where $-T$ denotes the inverse transpose, and $g(t)$ is some fixed matrix function. My question is if given the initial condition $e(0)$, whether $e(t)$ is determined uniquely? The answer is probably yes -- usually one could go so far as to integrate each side using the initial condition and then iterate the expression to obtain an 'explicit' expression for $e(t)$ (the path ordered exponential for example), but I am abit put-off by the appearance of the inverse $e^{-1}$, hence my slight apprehension.

Comment: You are correct to have doubts, just take a very simple special case $y'=-1/y$ where $y$ is a scalar, a $1\times 1$ matrix (and $g(t)=-1$). The solution ceases to exist in finite time.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The solution to that is $y(t)=\sqrt{c-2t}$. Do you mean then that at $t=c/2$, the derivative blows up?

Comment: Yes. And the solution function ceases to exist as real function. // For the general case you can likewise find $\frac{d}{dt}(e(t)^Te(t))=g(t)^T+g(t)$, and is is possible that the integral of the right side is not positive definite for all times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual [Picard-Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE systems applies, assuming of course $e(0)$ is invertible, so $e(t)$ is determined uniquely on some interval around $0$.  However, the solution may "blow up" or become singular
at some finite $t$.